# Upgrade from Rails 6 to 7 -- weird formatting problem in my MySQL database for date input

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, formatting, ruby-on-rails-7

Noticed this change after updating from rails 6 to 7. There is a weird formatting issue on dates in my MySQL db -- specifically the `updated_at` and `created_at` values.

It looks to be making it a float value, and i'm not sure why.

```
updated_at: Mon, 05 Feb 2024 15:18:57.000000000 PST -08:00,
created_at: Tue, 27 Jan 2009 17:07:18.000000000 PST -08:00
```

Comment: Is `Mon, 05 Feb 2024 15:18:57.000000000 PST -08:00` the new format or the old one? I'd guess that that's the new format and the old one was `Mon, 05 Feb 2024 15:18:57 PST -08:00`.

Comment: Yes, that's the new format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this just that you don't like the way it looks because that representation is perfectly valid according to the [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html):

> A `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` value can include a trailing fractional seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. In particular, any fractional part in a value inserted into a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column is stored rather than discarded. With the fractional part included, the format for these values is `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.fraction]'`.

You can find where and why this was implemented in:

- [Issue 42992](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/42992);
- [Pull 42993](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42993); and
- [Rails 7.0.0.alpha1 Change Log #2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-0-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md#rails-700alpha1-september-15-2021);